# Why Javascript function `arguments` is not an instance of Array in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Looking at a lot of NodeJS and Javascript code recently, it seems arguments is not an instance of Array but still behaves like one, so people do stuff like `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, ...)` or `[].slice.call(arguments)` which adds verbosity and increases hurdle for newbies to understand etc.. Is there a reason why arguments isnt an instance of Array or is this just one those bad parts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**NO**. `arguments` is a standalone object that just so happens to have a `length` property and the ability to use `[]` to index it. But otherwise, it is just an object, not an `Array` object.

And yes, this is indeed one of the bad parts of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I know it has extra properties like .callee etc.. but in an ideal world shouldnt they  have pointed the prototype to Array. so it would have splice/slice directly on it. I ask not to shoot the JS developer but only to clarify my understanding, ideally someone will turn around and say my idea is retarded becasue of x/y/z (fundamental misunderstanding etc..)

Comment: @mattcodes Yes, they definitely should have done that. JS has a bunch of quirks, and this is one of them.

Comment: Also don't assign to `arguments[0]` etc. as `arguments[0]` is *the exact same thing* as your first formal parameter, changing either, will also change the other one.

Comment: To be explicit, this isn't specific to Node.js.  It's in the JavaScript spec.